# Google API application restrictions do not work on the domain added in the configuration the console

Tags: firebase, api, vue.js, restriction

I am using firebase to do the authentication part of my website. I used in the Google API's the option "Key restrictions" by "HTTP referrers (websites)" I applied the rule according to the documentation.

```
* .example.com / *
```

But every time the rule is active, when trying to login it returns
"403"
Passing me that the domain has no permission, and I used the domain in the restriction rule.
Would anyone know why? Or a solution for that?

Thanks